# convert future builder to listview builder

Tags: flutter

i want to fetch data withour using future, can someone help me to convert it ? direct using listview.builder without using future builder. and how can i post it ? i already try it for a couple days and stuck here. please explain it too
thank you

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:latihan_dio/src/features/home/domain/user.dart';

import '../../../../dio_client.dart';

class myHomepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const myHomepage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<myHomepage> createState() => _myHomepageState();
}

class _myHomepageState extends State<myHomepage> {
  // List<User> users = [];
  var selectedIndex = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // fetchData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: FutureBuilder<List<User>>(
          future: fetchData(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return Text('Loading....');
              default:
                // if (snapshot.hasError) {
                //   return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                // } else {
                List<User>? data = snapshot.data;

                return ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Column(children: [
                      Text(data![index].firstName!),
                    ]);
                  },
                  itemCount: data?.length,
                );
            }
          }
          // },
          ),
    ));
  }

  Future<List<User>> fetchData() async {
    var Response = await DioClient().apiCall(
      url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2',
      requestType: RequestType.GET,
      // queryParameters: {},
    );
    if (Response.statusCode == 200) {
      List<dynamic> listUser = Response.data['data'];
      List<User> users = listUser.map((e) => User.fromJson(e)).toList();
      return users;
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }
}

// Future<void> fetchData() async {
//   var Response = await DioClient().apiCall(
//     url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2',
//     requestType: RequestType.GET,
//     // queryParameters: {},
//   );

//   // List<dynamic> listUser = Response.data;

//   // OR

//   List<dynamic> listUser =
//       Response.data['data']; // if you want to access data inside it

//   List<User> users = listUser.map((e) => User.fromJson(e)).toList();
// }
```

as u can see here is my homepage. i make a freeze class and using dio client here.

Comment: Just to be clear: What exactly is it that you don't want? Just the `FutureBuilder()` widget itself, or there is something else about futures that you don't like?

Comment: i just want to implement it with another way

Comment: Well that's what I'm saying, just "another way" is a bit vague...  You should try and be specific in your qns. But I see you got another way now, from @pmatatias, and if you're happy with that, all is good!

Comment: thank you so much for your help. i will learn by the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
class _myHomepageState extends State<myHomepage> {
  List<User> user = [];
  bool isLoading = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    initFunction();
    super.initState();
  }

 void initFunction() async {
  setState((){
    isLoading= true;
  })
  user = await fetchData();
  
  setState((){
   isLoading = false;
  });

 }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: isLoading 
          ? CircularProgressIndicator() 
          : ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Column(children: [
                      Text(user[index].firstName!),
                    ]);
                  },
                  itemCount: user.length,
                );
          ),
    ));
  }

  Future<List<User>> fetchData() async {
    var Response = await DioClient().apiCall(
      url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2',
      requestType: RequestType.GET,
      // queryParameters: {},
    );
    if (Response.statusCode == 200) {
      List<dynamic> listUser = Response.data['data'];
      List<User> users = listUser.map((e) => User.fromJson(e)).toList();
      return users;
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i got so many error

Comment: Undefined name 'user'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.

Comment: i change user to users. it works well

Comment: oh yes, my bad. there's a typo in users. 
great. glad to help